# How do I use 'update' & setState(prevState) together in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Right now I'm updating an inner object within my React Component which requires `update` from React. Here is my code:

```
const nameState = update(this.state, { userData: {name: {$set: e.target.value} }});
this.setState(nameState);
```

Now, the problem is that React's `setState` doesn't immediate make these changes but creates like a pending state change. So, the workaround this problem was using `prevState`. Something like this:

```
const enteredName = e.target.value;
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
   name : enteredName
  }));
```

So, how do I use `prevState` using my `update` function?

Comment: Please note, that according to the [React docs on update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), `update` is deprecated in favor of [kolodny/immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to how you updated `this.state`:

```
const enteredName = e.target.value;
this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, { userData: {name: {$set: enteredName} }}));
```